# Cannot get a symbol's value for the first time when using `setq-default`

Tags: variables, buffer-local, setq, setq-default

I can use `setq-default` to set a symbol's default value, as follows:

```
(with-temp-buffer

  (make-local-variable 'bar)
  (setq-default bar "xyz")
  (symbol-value 'bar))
```

When I first executed the above code, I got an error:

```
Symbol’s value as variable is void: bar
```

But when I tried executing it again, I got the expected return value: "xyz".

Why did I got an error the first time but succeeded the second time?

Answer (score 2):

Put the `make-local-variable` after the `setq-default`:

```lisp
(with-temp-buffer
  (setq-default bar "xyz")
  (make-local-variable 'bar)
  (symbol-value 'bar))
```

`setq-default` sets the global value. Doing what you did says there is a local value for `bar`, but it doesn't set that local value.  And neither does `setq-default` set that local value.

Doing it with what I wrote first sets the global value, then says that there's a local value.  And the local value is just the same as the global value.

As the doc string of `make-local-variable` tells you, you can also use `(set (make-local-variable 'bar "abc"))`.  (But that doesn't set the global value.)